# Ionic 2 firebase listener , adding reference to login page

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2

Need to add a reference to loginpage so that it can be pushed to the front of the stack. The firebase onAuthStateChanged is initiated on the page that loads after login page.

```
firebase.onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
  if(!user){
    this.nav.setRoot(LoginPage);
  }
});
```

This is not working. I don't know why.
i tried calling this from a service its does not work either.
I cant add this code to app.component.ts as there are a few pages which doesn't require the user to be logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use ionic events and publish a logged out event.

```
firebase.onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
 if(!user){
   this.events.publish("event:loggedOut");
 }
});
```

And In your app.component.ts subscribe to it.

```
this.events.subscribe("event:loggedOut",()=>{
  this.nav.push(LoginPage);
});
```

Dont forget to import Events from ionic-angular.